# How can I send an array created by a bunch of input fields via Ajax?

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, dictionary

I want to create an array by my input fields and send this array via ajax:

```js
var map = {};
$(".data_list").each(function() {
    map[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
});

alert(map.id); 
data = map;


$.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            data: {
                data: data,
            },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
            }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='data_list' name='id[]" + "' type='text' value='24'/>
<input class='data_list' name='name[]" + "' type='text' value='test'/>
```

But I think my array is not created correctly because my alert test is undefined.

Comment: then name of the inputs contains [], so the property id won't be defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jQuery https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ method on the form controls whose values you want to submit, and pass the result as your `data` parameter. Something like

```
$.ajax({ data: $(".data_list").serialize(), 
          /* url: ... etc .*./  });
```

Comment: btw I think you could use the shorthand `$.post()` here as well, instead of `$.ajax()`

Answer (score 1):

First, your inputs name have an extra " + ".
Second, the name contains the [], so you need to access it like and "associative array", `obj[attribute]` when it send the data, it will include the `[]` and your server side will be able to parse it as an array

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='data_list' name='id[]' type='text' value='24'/>
<input class='data_list' name='name[]' type='text' value='test'/>
```

```html
var map = {};
$(".data_list").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr("name"));
    map[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
});

alert(map["id[]"]); 
data = map;


$.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            data: {
                data: data,
            },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
            }
})
```